# Execute WQL Query on Remote Machine

Tags: go, wmi

I am using this [WMI library](https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi) for executing WQL query in Go language. I am able to execute the sample code in local machine. However, I need to execute the WQL query on a remote machine. The [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/StackExchange/wmi#Client.Query) for the `Query` method I use reads as shown below:

> By default, the local machine and default namespace are used. These
>   can be changed using connectServerArgs. See
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720.aspx for details.

However, I am not sure how to pass the `connectServerArgs` correctly. 
Could somebody please help me with a sample declaration of this argument and how to pass it to `Query` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720.aspx), the signature of `ConnectServer` method is:

```
objwbemServices = .ConnectServer( _
  [ ByVal strServer ], _
  [ ByVal strNamespace ], _
  [ ByVal strUser ], _
  [ ByVal strPassword ], _
  [ ByVal strLocale ], _
  [ ByVal strAuthority ], _
  [ ByVal iSecurityFlags ], _
  [ ByVal objwbemNamedValueSet ] _
)
```

so try something like:

```
c.Query(wqlQery, dst, "your-remote.server.net or IP address", 
    "root\CIMV2", "DomainName\UserName", "secret password")
```

Comment: do i need to actively close the c object after im done with the execution, im not sure if it "releases" itself or not